# Combine two columns into tuple in polars python API

Tags: python, data-manipulation, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe that looks like:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"bid": [1, 2, 3], "fid": [4, 5, 6]})
```

I would like to combine the two columns row wise into a tuple so that the result looks like:

```
pl.DataFrame({"bfid": [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]})
```

I tried to do this: `df2.with_columns(pl.map(['bid', 'fid'], lambda x: (x[0], x[1])))` which is wrong but also quite slow if I try to scale up to large datasets.

Is there a better way to do this type of data manipulation?  End result should be:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

So to combine row-wise columns of a dataframe in polars is pretty straight forward since this kind of functionality is already built in.

```
df.select(pl.concat_list(pl.col(["bid", "fid"])).alias("bfid"))


shape: (3, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ bfid      │
│ ---       │
│ list[i64] │
╞═══════════╡
│ [1, 4]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [2, 5]    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [3, 6]    │
└───────────┘
```

If you want to know more about row-wise and list computation in polars, there is a wonderful section in the [user-guide](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/expressions/lists/)

Comment: Is there a simple and efficient way to achieve the same thing but with tuples instead of lists in `bfid`?

Comment: Tuples aren't a supported data type in polars. So you could transfer the lists into tuples but they would be stored in polars than as Object but the support for Object is very limited.

Comment: Got it. The thing is I needed hashable objects to call `.map_dict()`, I've finally circumvented the issue by concatenating my DataFrame columns into a new column of strings.